# What happens in DateFormatter when Locale is initialized with an invalid identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, locale, dateformatter

I noticed in our product that some legacy code is trying to initialize `Locale` for `DateFormatter` with invalid identifiers. (e.g. `Locale(identifier: "UTC")`)

Weirdly code is working fine for parsing POSIX dates. And I know that it is not defaulting to `Locale.current` because if I set `DateFormatter.locale` to `Locale.current` myself, it doesn't work.

So I'm curious what it actually defaults to in this case, since I couldn't find anything in documentation. Perhaps it defaults to `en_US_POSIX` (since it works how we would expect from `en_US_POSIX`) but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Define "code is working fine". I assume it's rather "working fine on my device which is set to en_US". I can't give an exact answer to your question, as you said this is not documented. I do however suspect that the "development language" set in the Xcode project plays a role here.

Comment: @JanBrinker It works as I would expect from `"en_US_POSIX"`. And can parse POSIX dates correctly. Yet I cannot be sure if it actually uses `"en_US_POSIX"` because I'm not testing all the possible cases to confirm this.

Though I can confirm it is not working same as `Locale.current`. Since if I set to `Locale.current` it cannot parse my POSIX dates.